# Steam API: Type Error and turning JSON into CSV?

Tags: python, json, csv

I'm trying to figure out why I keep getting a Type error when trying to pull out from the Steam API, I'm trying to create a dictionary to then turn into a CSV file, I know this is in JSON so my question is two fold, how to create a CSV type of data and how to take the JSON info that I have into that. The idea of this method is to get a list of AppIDs so I can find their prices:

Code:

```
def steamlibrarypull(steamID, key):
    #Pulls out a CSV of Steam libraries
    steaminfo = {
        'key': key,
        'steamid': steamID,
        'format':'JSON',
        'include_appinfo':'1'
    }
    r = requests.get('http://api.steampowered.com/IPlayerService/GetOwnedGames/v0001/', params=steaminfo)
    d = json.loads(r.content)
    I = d['response']['games']
    B = {}
    for games in I:
        B[I['name']] = I['appid']
    return B
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "steam.py", line 46, in <module>
    print steamlibrarypull(76561197960434622, key)
  File "steam.py", line 44, in steamlibrarypull
    B[I['name']] = I['appid']
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str
```

Comment: FYI, `requests` objects have a `json()` method that returns a Python dict. Also, a coding hint: use meaningful variable names. You're not writing assembler on a chip with 64K of memory - be descriptive. You'll thank yourself when you come back to the code in a year, and you'll avoid getting killed by anyone else that wants to use your code.

Comment: While it does, I want to only grab specific parts of the Json from the requests.get.

Comment: I understand that. What I meant was you could replace `d = json.loads(r.content)` with `d = r.json()` and not have to worry about importing the `json` module. Heck, you could even go with `I = r.json()['response']['games']` and skip a few lines.

Comment: Also, you you [edit] your question and post the complete text of the error you're getting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not referencing the iterator properly.

```
def steamlibrarypull(steamID, key):
    #Pulls out a CSV of Steam libraries
    steaminfo = {
        'key': key,
        'steamid': steamID,
        'format':'JSON',
        'include_appinfo':'1'
    }
    r = requests.get('http://api.steampowered.com/IPlayerService/GetOwnedGames/v0001/', params=steaminfo)
    d = json.loads(r.content)
    I = d['response']['games']
    B = {}
    for games in I:
        B[games['name']] = games['appid']
 return B
```

That will return a dictionary of name:appid.  You will then need to iterate through it and write it to a file.

```
with open('games.csv', 'w') as f:
for key, value in B.items():
   f.write("%s,%s\r\n" % (key, value))
```

Comment: While this works: I get this error now: UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u2122' in position 19: ordinal not in range(128)

Comment: yes, steams api response is in utf-8 and will need to be encoded to such before you can work with it in python.  you can do a dictionary comprehension like so:  `encodeddict = {k.encode('utf8'): v for k, v in B.items()}` or `B[games['name'].encode('utf8')] = games['appid']`.  if you are going to work with the steam api in python you will need to convert to utf-8 early on since game names and usernames will most often have a utf-8 character in them

Comment: here is a [link](https://github.com/briggleman/condensation/tree/master/condensation) to the steam api wrapper i am working on.  this may help you get started.  keep in mind i am still working on this and will most likely clean it up to make it more efficient.

Comment: B[games['name'].encode('utf8')] = games['appid'] is the best place to put it.

Answer (score 0):

Your `for` loop is not doing what you want it to do. Use this:

```
for game in I:
    B[game['name']] = game['appid']
return B
```

`I` in this case (I'm assuming, since I don't have a Steam account) is a list containing a number of dicts, each with a `'name'` field and an `'appid'` field, among others. Your `for` loop is iterating over each of these dicts, and you want to store just those two fields in a new dict named `B`. However, in your code, `I['name']` doesn't work, as `I` is a list, and can only be indexed by integers, hence the error. However, when iterating over this list of dicts, `game['name']` will work just fine, because dicts are indexed by their keys.

As far as turning this data into a CSV, there are a number of questions on SO on this topic, so just use Google to search for them.

Comment: While that's good, is there a way to not have to out put it into a seperate file? I can't find one that can't do that. ideally I'd like to just put it into a variable so I can call on it to grab prices.

Comment: @Marorin what "file" are you talking about? "*I'd like to just put it into a variable so I can call on it to grab prices.*" What "*it*" are you talking about here? `B` is a variable. If you have a game called `FUBAR` with app id `12345`, then `print(B['FUBAR'])` will give you the app id. I'm not sure what exactly you're asking.

Comment: I'd like to be able to create CSV data but in a manner that doesn't have it outputted into a seperate file. Like how one can parse JSON from a GET request and then input it into a dictionary.

Comment: @Marorin there are no separate files in my answer. Like I said in my comment above, `d = r.json()` creates a dict `d` with the parsed data returned in `r`. The next line filters that dict somewhat and stores the results in `I`. Finally, my code filters that some more, and stores everything in the `B` dict. No outputting to files at all. If you need help on converting dicts to CSVs, just search, as there are plenty of resources out there.

Comment: I guess a bigger question is: What are you ultimately trying to do? What is the CSV for?

Comment: The CSV is to take and to use into a second request to pull out prices for games through their gameids.

Comment: @Marorin if all you need is the game's app id, why do you need a CSV? They are useful for **storing** information for later retrieval (for example, by another program), but they're not so good for use as a dynamic data structure. Why not just use the `B` dict for the purpose of retrieving each game's ID? A CSV shouldn't be necessary at all.

Comment: https://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/User:RJackson/StorefrontAPI#appdetails Seems to require that one inputs a CSV, hence why I asked.

Comment: i believe you may be going about this the wrong way.  by going this route you will hit the steam api request per second limit and will not get all of your data back.  the api has a limit of 1 call per 2 seconds.  your code will make a call faster than that. you will need to put the appids into a list and send them 100 at a time as that's the upper limit on the number of items you can request from steam at a time.  i've written an api wrapper in python for a majority of their api but have not done any unittesting or optimization on it but would be happy to share it with you.

Comment: While the wrapper is appreciated, I would like to do this from scratch if possible. The main point of my code is to do visualization with this data.